# Pasar datos entre diferentes UserControls

Tags: .net, usercontrol

Tengo el siguiente esquema montado en Visual Studio (C#.net)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es poder traer los datos del Textbox al UserControl2. He probado instanciando UserControl1 y cambiando el nivel de proteción del Textbox a publico, desde el objeto puedo acceder al Textbox.Text pero este me lo trae vacio.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Config Example = new Config();
    MessageBox.Show(Example.textBox1.Text);
}
```

¿Cómo podría pasar los datos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal vez el problema que tienes es que instancias el `UserControl` pero no das tiempo a que el usuario interactue con el y cuando le pides el valor del texto, este está vacio.

La manera que vi de resolver tu problema es creando una propiedad en el `UserControl` que lleva el `textbox` llamada **EditText** a travez de la cual podras acceder al texto del textbox, así como cambiarlo, de todas formas si luego vas a trabajar especificamente con otras propiedades del `textbox` puedes cambiarle el acceso al mismo como lo hicistes arriba. Luego en el otro `UserControl` cree un evento llamado **ClickBtn** con el cual puedo asignar una operación cuando se presione el botón. Aquí esta el código:

**UserControl1** (El del textbox)

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string EditText
    {
        get { return textBox1.Text; }
        set { textBox1.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

**UserControl2** (El del botón)

```
public partial class UserControl2 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ClickBtn += UserControl2_ClickBtn;
    }

    private void UserControl2_ClickBtn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public event EventHandler ClickBtn;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClickBtn.Invoke(sender, e);
    }
}
```

En el formulario de mi app tengo este codigo

```
private void userControl21_ClickBtn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(userControl1.EditText);
}
```

Aqui te dejo una imagen de como funciona:

[image: Ejemplo de ejecucion]

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda, hasta el punto de involucrarte en hacer un gif con el resultado, lo agradezco mucho, de veras. He estado probando, tanto en mi proyecto como en uno nuevo, (por si fuese problema mio), pero el resultado es el mismo, la ventana emergente nunca se ejecuta. También decir que no puedo llamar a userControl1.EditText sin antes instanciarlo, una vez lo instancio puedo hacer compilar el código sin problema, pero el resultado es el anteriormente dicho; El botón no funciona y no genera la alerta. ¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Yo en la respuesta que te puse tengo 2 UserControl que son los que ves coloreados, en el formulario son instanciados en el constructor y a travez del evento que hice en el control del boton puedo asignarle una operacion al boton del mismo desde el formulario o desde donde lo tenga instanciado.

Comment: Si quieres tener acceso al textbox del UserControl desde el otro UserControl puedo sugerirte que en el constructor le pases un parametro de ese tipo lo recojas en una variable privada o protegida y ya podrias acceder al textbox desde el UserControl del boton

Comment: Me vas a disculpar pero no tengo ni la menor idea de commo hacer eso, ¿sería mucho pedir si pudieses pasarme el proyecto del gif y decirme que nombre recibe esos staments para poder estudiarlos? Muchas gracias! :)

Comment: Dame tu correo para pasartelo..

Comment: revisa a ver ya te lo comparti en dropbox

Comment: Perfecto, muchisimas gracias por las molestias, de veras :-)

Comment: Hay dos comprimidos el que se llama controles independientes puedes ver como trabajo con el cuadro de texto desde el formulario sin mezclar los usercontrols, en el otro ejemplo el que dice dependientes si mezclo el primero en el segundo para poder tener acceso al cuadro de texto te puse algunos comentarios

Comment: Disculpa otra vez, creo que tanto el independiente como el dependiente son el mismo proyecto, ya que son identicos en contenido, y en ninguno encuentro comentarios. He seguido paso por paso cada parte de código que tiene tus user controls y formulario en un proyecto aparte, pero vuelvo a tener el mismo problema, la alerta no se ejecuta. ¿Me estoy olvidando de cambiar alguna propiedad?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81126/discussion-between-dariel-ramos-diaz-de-villegas-and-omar).